# Run Mysql-CLuster

Tags: mysql-error-1064, mysql, mysql-cluster

I am trying to test mysql-cluster but I have to run it.

I succeeded installation and configuration but the last step of running doesn't work.

I have a major error, when I run

`/home/sonia/mysqlc/bin/mysqld --defaults-file=conf/my.cnf &`

I get this output

```
2014-03-18 17:55:09 30535 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Address already in use
2014-03-18 17:55:09 30535 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 5021 ?
2014-03-18 17:55:09 30535 [ERROR] Aborting
```

I already tested different port : 3305-3306-5000 & 5021.

Someone has an idea please?

Comment: `netstat` will tell what runs there.

Comment: You should see what is listening on port 5021

Answer (score 1):

Check what's using port 5021 :

`$ sudo netstat -atnp | grep 3306`

Stop/Kill all mysqld instances

`$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
 $ sudo killall mysqld`

Make sure that your Management/API servers are up

`$ ndb_mgm
ndb_mgm> show`

then start your MySQL node normally.